# How to return a value from an Interaction

Tags: java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have a screenplay interaction class that makes a select from a postgres DB. I would like to know how to return the result set using this screenplay pattern.

What I have tried by now is changing the returned type on the method "public  void performAs(T actor)" to "public  ResultSet performAs(T actor)"

But then I have the following problems:

```
Error:(12, 8) java: jarv.serenity.carnival.interactions.dbRelated.SelectDataBase is not abstract and does not override abstract method <T>performAs(T) in net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Performable
Error:(23, 40) java: <T>performAs(T) in jarv.serenity.carnival.interactions.dbRelated.SelectDataBase cannot implement <T>performAs(T) in net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Performable
  return type java.sql.ResultSet is not compatible with void
Error:(21, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

This is the class file

```
package jarv.serenity.carnival.interactions.dbRelated;

import jarv.serenity.carnival.dataBaseConection.DataBaseDriver;
import jarv.serenity.carnival.model.Users;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Interaction;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Tasks.instrumented;

public class SelectDataBase implements Interaction {

    private final DataBaseDriver dbDriver;
    private ResultSet rs=null;

    public SelectDataBase(DataBaseDriver dbDriver) {
        this.dbDriver = dbDriver;
    }

    @Override
    @Step("Selecting from DB")
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
        try
        {
            Statement st = dbDriver.getConn().createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * From users");
            dbDriver.disconect();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            dbDriver.disconect();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getResults(){
        return rs;
    }

    public static Interaction select(DataBaseDriver dbDriver) {
        return instrumented(SelectDataBase.class, dbDriver);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return rs.toString();
    }
}
```

Right now I am able to perform the select operation but not to retrieve the result set.

I would like to be able to retrieve it or have it returned to any task or questions that use this interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Screenplay pattern, interactions are not meant to return values, just to perform some action on the system under test. You use Questions for querying the state of the system. It would be easier if you shared the overall problem you are trying to solve, but since your example is about querying users, you could have a test that checks that you can add a user to the system via a UI admin page:

```
@Test
public void add_a_user_to_the_system() {

    Actor ada = Actor.named("Ada").describedAs("an admin");

    when(ada).attemptsTo(
            AddANewUser.called("Jack")
    );

    then(ada).should(
            seeThat(KnownUsers.inTheSystem(),
                    contains(hasProperty("name", equalTo(("Jack"))))
            )
    );
}
```

(It would probably be more efficient to search for the user by name in this case, but I wanted to keep it close to your example).

To do this, you might have an `AddANewUser` class which uses the admin screens to add a new user:

```
class AddANewUser implements Performable {

    public static Performable called(String userName) {
        return instrumented(AddANewUser.class, userName);
    }

    private final String userName;

    AddANewUser(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
        // Add a new user called userName via the UI
    }
}
```

Then you would check that this user exists using a question:

```
@Subject("known users")
static class KnownUsers implements Question<List<ApplicationUser>> {

  public static KnownUsers inTheSystem() { return new KnownUsers(); }

  @Override
  public List<ApplicationUser> answeredBy(Actor actor) {
      // Query the database and convert the result set to ApplicationUsers
      return ...;
  }
}
```

You could also create an Ability class to centralise the JDBC queries, credentials etc.

Comment: Thanks @John Smart ... yeah I noticed later that using question I could check the DB  table state.  On this cases I was just requested to use the Screenplay pattern to simple operations on a DB (Select, Insert, Update, Delete) and I was looking for an option to ensure that a Delete, Insert or whatever was performed...I guess I need a question like userExists to check that It was indeed deleted or inserted.

I will continue working on it as a self learning - practice project. Again Thank you!!